# Can IT Support be a good career?

Tags: software-industry, work-experience, work-life-balance, tech-industry

Most IT Professionals I believe start off in an IT Support role.
I was thinking that maybe doing Help Desk or Desktop Support can be a good career instead of like System Admin or Network Admin

So what is your experience or opinion on someone who can make a career in IT Support?

Can it be a good career with a Bachelors Degree?

Is there advancement?

Can you pull in 50K to 60K a year possibly doing IT Support?

Can you have good work life balance?

or does it have more cons due to outsourcing, low pay etc?

Comment: 1)Supporting **what**, specifically?  2)maybe. 3)Depends, 4)no 5)After a fashion, 6)no 7) see six

Comment: Anyone who tells you they can see more than 7 years into the future of IT in any respect is a liar or a lunatic.

Comment: My experience is that it can be good if you like Support, Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes, only you can decide if it has "more cons". "Can IT Support be a good career?" = yes, it can.

Comment: I always get the feeling that help desk work is looked down on and I wonder if that is the reason for the down votes.  It can be a great career.

Comment: @JasonJ The downvotes have nothing to do with the fact that it's about IT Support. "Can <blank> be a good career?" is completely subjective and off-topic here, regardless of the job being asked about.

Comment: @DavidK I get where you are coming from, but I think that there are some cases where a general "subjective" discussion can be valuable.  I suspect that I may have to start writing a META post to discuss since now I want to discuss the merits.....

Answer (score 3):

**So what is your experience or opinion on someone who can make a career in IT Support?**

Subjectivity should not matter to you - it is definitely a great place to make your bones, get intimate with various technology stacks with a high-level understanding and definitely helps with customer-facing skills. It will get stagnant eventually but having a sh*t-hot Help Desk/TSR on staff is always a life saver

**Can it be a good career with a Bachelors Degree?**

That is more-or-less HR-centric, same reason why you see some job requirements for a Tier 1 Help Desk Analyst want a CISSP, MCIE or other higher-level certs, I began as a Help Desk Analyst and I am now a Program Manager and freelance a lot on my spare time, I do not even have an Associates, nor a cert, so it can be a great career without one - I am sure company promotion policies will dictate if getting one will make it "good"

**Is there advancement?**

There are definitely different "levels" to being a Help Desk/Support person - the different ITIL Tiers (I/II/III), you can be an analyst, maybe specialize in a specific technology stack within the organization (Subject Matter Expert, aka, SME in MS Project or some sort of web-app) and become a Manager/Supervisor obviously if the hierarchy permits

**Can you pull in 50K to 60K a year possibly doing IT Support?**

In a specialized/hybrid role, or managerial/supervisory, I would say it is possible. That greatly depends on locale, company size, scope of work and cost of living - I'd say generally a Tier I Help Desk, bottom of the barrel, will be bringing in 25-30K; but a higher level individual with some certs/degree, 5+ years of experience and in a manager/supervisor/lead position can probably bring that in.

**Can you have good work life balance?**

That is totally company based. A regular 8 hour work day (whether 7-3, 9-5, etc) is fine. Some companies do 12/12 with 3 days off, some work weekends, some telecommute/work remotely, some are on-call...it all depends.

**[...]cons due to outsourcing, low pay etc?**

In my experience in the IT field I have seen a lot of big-box companies hire in massive droves of remote (work-from-home) workers, with high-turnover, some are on set 1099 contracts and that can drive the price down. That depends on what you are doing, some person wanting to be an Xbox Tech Support person probably fits into that. Outsourcing/off-shore teams can also bite into it, but organizations that use proprietary software, or have a huge/specific technology stack will not be affected. For instance, I can train someone up to read off a script to help someone with TurboTax, but I will have to recruit a SME in MS Project Server or TFS 2015 - cannot train that reasonably fast.

I would suggest you found an area of support to focus on - you may find you want to move up, a lot of people do. As I mentioned I was a Help Desk guy, that became a Sys Admin, that became a Network Engineer then a Security Architect and now I PM/PGM - but you still need a specific area. I was all about Linux, some places have a bunch of MS products/applications, others are Citrix based, some shops are all over the place.

You can definitely make a career - but do you want to? Long hours, high turnover, not a lot of room to move past an entry-level supervisory/managerial role, heavy workload? I'd use it as a jumping point and move on.

Comment: Good insights..